# Wordpress Role based custom registration form

Tags: wordpress, forms, registration, role

I am trying 2 Role based registration. Ex: Role1, Role2

Once click Registration link then select any Role(role1, role2) after form field automatically change. It's possible ?

**Example:**
**Select Role : (Role1) or (Role2)** Once select role form automatically changed.
**Role1 Form**
Name:
Email:
Address:

**Role2 Form**
Company Name:
Phone Number:
Company Address:

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery for a simple answer:

before the get_header() function
wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

your selector element:

```
   <select name="drop" id="drop">
   <option name="role1">role1</option>
   <option name="role2">role2</option>
   </select>
```

set your form 2 elements as display none.

Html form:

```
   <div class="forma" style="display: none;"> 
   question 1
   question 2 
   </div>

   <div class="formhidden"  style="display: none;">
   company name: <input type="text"  name="company" /> 
   </div>
```

Jquery (enqueue jquery with wp_enqueue('jQuery'); see codex for this. Add the  to the page either in the header or footer (escape php) sometimes you need to change position for it to work..)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#drop').change(function() { 

           if(jQuery('#drop').val()=="role2") {
            jQuery('.formhidden').show();
               jQuery('.forma').hide();
           } else {

            jQuery(".forma").show();
               jQuery('.formhidden').hide();
            }

      });
   });
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dheffernan/MHnfe/

now when you select a role, it hides one form and shows the other.

Comment: I'm trying but it's not working. I'm Check http://jsfiddle.net/dheffernan/MHnfe/. But how to work Role1 form. And another thing how to integrate WordPress role here. I mean Author and Subscriber roles.

Comment: just but form1 before thre

Comment: Hi David, Thanks to your replay. See my requirements. Once select role hide form. For example I'm select Role 1 and showing role 1 Forms. And select Role 2 form showing only Role2 forms.

Comment: i updated the jquery, you need to include jquery on the page to make it work. The roles you mention are a side issue, when you are running the formaction, you can user wp_insert_user() or wp_update_user() to give them the role

Comment: Hi David. How are you?. I hope you are fine. I want some help. I follow your code. It's working fine without required fields. But Required fields is not working. I mean form not submit. For example: Form1 some fields required and Form2 are some fields required. I'm submit form1 But form not submit it's required form2 fields.

Comment: hi good! can you create a new question with your form code and ill have a look? so your html + php process code. put the link here !

Comment: Sorry David. Unfortunately my question accepting some problem. I have share my working website link here?

Comment: yes you can do, i might be able to see it from there. What i think is happening when you select some values as required, it is looking for the hidden fields to be populated as well!

Comment: ok i see the problem, your javascript validation is calling errors because fields that aren't in focus are not being filled in. It will submit if you fill in all fields. What you need to do is control the required elements. you could set a class for each form field eg class="input individual" / organization and then jQuery('.individual').prop('required',false); or true when changing forms. If you cant do this put the html and js into a question and ill create a fiddle!

Comment: Hi David Thanks your replay. I’m using Theme my login.  Now I removed “required’ text. Because it’s not working in IE 7-9. Please Now Check http://bit.ly/1hZ4tIP How fix this. please help.

Comment: Hi Mate, Finally I got some solution. Finally it’s working fine. 
Thank you, thank you very much your help. I love you so much.